# can't find /run/user/65534 in /etc/fstab

Tags: 16.04, mount, fstab, dialog

I have a version of `xenial` running on a VM (due to compatibility reasons) and whenever I boot it up, I get an error dialog that reads:

> **Error** mount: can't find /run/user/65534 in /etc/fstab

and I was wondering what this is all about, why this shows up and how i get rid of it.

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=6e415079-1461-4b10-bfb2-f2ea8742bcc8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=fdcbb1a5-f6b9-4994-bae6-c4c97d2f6a1b none            swap    sw              0       0
```

--

```
$ grep nobody /etc/passwd
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

--

```
$ sudo grep nobody /etc/shadow
nobody:*:17953:0:99999:7:::
```

Comment: That line shouldn't be in /etc/fstab.

Comment: @heynnema it isn't, I added my fstab on top!

Comment: Where do you get / see this error ?

Comment: 65534 is the id of [nobody user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186568/what-is-nobody-user-and-group). Did you tweaked that user privileges/permissions? What is the output of `grep nobody /etc/passwd`?

Comment: @SorenA in dialog box when LXQt starts

Comment: @Kulfy I get: `nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin`

Comment: And what about `sudo grep nobody /etc/shadow`?

Comment: @Kulfy `nobody:*:17953:0:99999:7:::`

Comment: Do you use NFS?

Comment: @Kulfy no, not for this machine